# There is any function like setGeoJSON in HERE maps

Tags: html, mapbox, here-api

In Map box there is a function for read featured geoJson setGeoJSON(geojson1), but there is any function in HERE Maps similar to that.

I have a featured list json array with coordinates.   In Map Box we can display that as follows

```
            var featureLayer =myLayer.setGeoJSON(geojson1);
            map.fitBounds(featureLayer.getBounds());
```

there is any way in HERE Maps ?

Answer (score 0):

The API documentation has this:

https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics_api_nlp/h-data-geojson-reader.html

There's even code in the class description how to set it up. I haven't tried it myself, though.

Comment: I saw that but there is a description for read geojson files. I need a read geojson string directly